# What does the "enable" app feature actually do in the app catalog

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, app

Trying to get a clearer understanding of what "enable" means. In this [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/use-app-catalog), and in the feature description, Msft implies that you if you enable an app "End users should see this app as an option to add to sites". So I would expect to have to remove the app from a site once added to stop it functioning. But if you uncheck "enable", it seems the app does stop working.

Example: I uploaded an spfx extension to the app catalog that injects a stylesheet. Since I want this to be optional by site, I didn't deploy tenant wide. When "enabled", I can add the app to a site via "add an app" and the stylesheet renders in the code for that site. If I uncheck "enable", the app is no longer available in add an app as expected, but also the functionality no longer works and the stylesheet doesn't get called.

Once the functionality is confirmed, I can make the description associated with the enabled field more accurate, but don't want to change it till I'm sure.

Comment: Got any updates on the behavior? This behavior is obviously not expected / different from SP2013, for example.

Comment: FYI - added this issue https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/OfficeDocs-SharePoint/issues/3087

Answer (score 0):

It's not just about enabling the app. It's also about making it available.

So when I say making the App available it means it should be available for the entire context wherein you want to make use of it .

In your case, it wouldn't be possible to enable the app , use it's properties to drive something and then disable it by unchecking .

Once you uncheck and disable the App, the app becomes meaningless in the context and all it's properties and functions all become meaningless to SharePoint .

So this wouldn't help you .

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, enabling an app provides the capability of full function of this feature.

When you add the spfx extension to the app catalog, you have access to the app feature, but it is not in function. “Enable” means "switch on".

When you disable a feature, it gets turned off, but it is still reachable in the site (collection).

Comment: That was my assumption too, but isn't what Msft's description implies: "End users should see this app as an option to add to sites".Nothing there about turning the app's functionality on or off. So sounds like just another case of Msft's loose command of language/

Comment: It’s just a matter of expression. Microsoft will use more official and professional language in the documents, leading to less user-friendly.